# GoogleService-Info.plist not created

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm upgrading from an earlier version of Google Analytics for my iOS app and when I follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/), I click the button to create a configuration file and nothing happens.  Anyone else experience this?  Is there a default GoogleService-Info.plist that I can use and customize?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, looks like they would work for others.  Unfortunately, I just couldn't get Cocoa Pods to upgrade the analytics, so I switched tactics and used the [sdk](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download) directly.  This worked fine, hopefully others have better luck!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug on their site. It worked for me 2 weeks ago. However you have already found Googles Guide - the config file does not contain any complicated settings, however you can download the Sample Apps and get your initial **GoogleService-Info.plist** file from there:

```
pod try Google
```

from

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/code-samples#try-the-sdk-demos-using-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

**Steps for getting configuration if your first time login to google developer accoun**t.

```
1. open google developer console.
2. login to developer console.
3. create project with valid name.
4. then goto the API section & enable GCM API. 
5. Then get the configuration file.
```